# How to create a encrypted Sqlite Database?

Tags: java, sqlite, encryption

I am using a **Sq-lite database** as a back end in my Java project. The database created and executed fine. Now i must Encrypt the Database from others. I searched a lot but i can't get a good solutions. If any one give me an idea **how to develop an Encrypted database.**  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this :
http://sqlite-crypt.com/index.htm
If you wanna do it in java, you can crypt it like any other file : 
http://cs.saddleback.edu/rwatkins/CS4B/Crypto/FileEncryptor.html